# Recover from ProtocolException in HttpClient

Tags: java, httpclient

I sometimes get such stacktraces when downloading from HttpClient:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out, at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method), 
...
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:170), 
[wrapped] 
org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProtocolException: The server example.com failed to respond with a valid HTTP response,
```

I've tried to recover from these errors by using a custom HttpMethodRetryHandler, but it seems I don't even enter the retryMethod(). It may be due to the fact the wrapped exception in SocketTimeoutException is a ProtocolException, which inherits from HttpException, and thus is not eligible to recovery, if I correctly understand the code of HttpMethodDirector class.

```
 while (true) {
       execCount++;
       try {
           ...
       } catch (HttpException e) {
           // filter out protocol exceptions which cannot be recovered from
           throw e;
       } catch (IOException e) {
           // test if this method should be retried
```

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/exception-handling.html says

> ProtocolException signals a violation of the HTTP specification. It is
>   important to note that HTTP proxies and HTTP servers can have
>   different level of HTTP specification compliance. It may be possible
>   to recover from some HTTP protocol exceptions by configuring
>   HttpClient to be more lenient about non-fatal protocol violations.

How can i achieve that? Is there an API allowing this or should I implement the mecanism to retry requests failing with HttpException?

Comment: Have you tried `configuring HttpClient to be more lenient about non-fatal protocol violations.`?

Comment: Actually, I did not find how to do that :-/

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of `http.protocol.*` configuration parameters that are defined [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/preference-api.html). You need to carefully look at each one of them and figure out what is the optimum leniency you need.

Comment: Which one should I use?